# FetchXML Understanding Distinct

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I am learning FetchXML and am currently new to it.

I tried looking at the documentation located [here](http://msxrmtools.com/fetchxml/reference) but I did not find it very helpful

What does this line mean:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
```

What does the `mapping="logical"` part mean?
What does the `distinct="true"` part mean?

Answer (score 1):

As per [FetchXML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/fetchxml-schema) we have two enum values namely internal & logical for mapping attribute. We have to use `mapping="logical"` in our queries & internal may be for Platform usage (my guess).

```
    <xs:attribute name="mapping">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
          <xs:enumeration value="internal" />
          <xs:enumeration value="logical" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
```

`distinct="true"` will remove the duplicate values in your resultset. This is similar to SQL concept.

[Refer & read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-fetchxml-aggregation#count-distinct-columns)