# Do not return duplicates in Dynamics 365 Web API data retrieval query

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm using the following query parameters to retrieve all active membership records with the Dynamics 365 Web API (PHP).

```
$params = array(
    "$select" => "member_number,statuscode,statecode",
    "$filter" => "statecode eq 1"
);
```

This returns all active membership records (statecode 1). However, because a particular member can have a soon-to-expire membership and a recently-renewed membership (among others), a single entity can return multiple active records, bloating my results. I only need to know once if an entity is active, not six times.

Is there a way to exclude duplicate records so that I only receive one instance of each active membership record? I'm looking for the Dynamics 365 Web API equivalent of using `DISTINCT` in an SQL query.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, and thanks for your answer. As I'm unfamiliar with FetchXML, I'm going to need to set up a separate Dynamics testing environment to experiment with this. I aim to do this over the next few days and will certainly accept your answer if I can get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend you to play around with the fetchxml queries in XrmToolBox FetchXML builder..

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I'll check that out today.

Comment: Were you able to sort it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't had a chance to attempt this. The temporary workaround has been to use the 'startswith(entity, 'value')' filter in my cURL request parameters. This returns a manageable amount of results because I'm filtering out a huge amount of unneeded results. However, I'm still getting duplicates on the results that I am returning. So, I would still like to leave this question open and explore your answer asap, as the current solution is really only a temporary one. Again, sorry for the delay, and thanks for your answer! It's been on my mind more than you know!

Answer (score 0):

I am not from php background but I will try.

`Distinct` can be used only in FetchXML query, and [fetchxml can be used along with web api](https://dreamingincrm.com/2017/01/15/executing-large-fetchxml-with-webapi/).

I can find the below example - an online reference with [AlexaCRM toolkit](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/dynamics-webapi-toolkit/wiki/Tutorial).

```
$fetchXML = <<<FETCHXML
<fetch mapping="logical" distinct="true"> 
    <entity name="new_membership">
        <attribute name="member_number" /> 
    </entity>
</fetch>
FETCHXML;

$fetchExpression = new \AlexaCRM\Xrm\Query\FetchExpression( $fetchXML );
$collection = $client->RetrieveMultiple( $fetchExpression );
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do not recall the WebAPI having a Distinct operator, [FetchXML does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228271/fetchxml-understanding-distinct).

And, you can run FetchXML via the API

For example, without `Distinct`:

`https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?fetchXml=
<fetch mapping='logical'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' />
    <filter>
        <condition attribute='fullname' operator='eq' value='Nick Saban'/>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>`

Returns:

`{
   "@odata.context":"https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#contacts(fullname,contactid)",
   "value":[
      {
         "@odata.etag":"W/\"175969918\"",
         "fullname":"NICK SABAN",
         "contactid":"ca338867-8831-e511-8103-c4346bac6974"
      },
      {
         "@odata.etag":"W/\"187905023\"",
         "fullname":"NICK SABAN",
         "contactid":"fff12a11-ef85-e511-810a-fc15b4281ce0"
      }
   ]
}`

With `Distinct`:
`https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts?fetchXml=
<fetch mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' />
    <filter>
        <condition attribute='fullname' operator='eq' value='Nick Saban'/>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>`

Returns:

`{
   "@odata.context":"https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#contacts(fullname)",
   "value":[
      {
         "fullname":"NICK SABAN"
      }
   ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Since Dynamics supports ODATA 4.0, you can query using $apply in this way:

```
$params = array(
    "$apply" => "groupby((member_number))",
    "$filter" => "statecode eq 1"
);
```

This query would return a different JSON but with a collection of the distinct "member_numbers" in your entity. Hope it helps.

This answer is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839073/select-distinct-values-with-odata). Please check it out for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This looks promising, and I'm testing it out now. I'll update if/when I find a solution. Thanks again!